# How to remove the rounded corners from JavaFX buttons

Tags: css, javafx

I've noticed that buttons in JavaFX have rounded corners, which means when you have a grid of them there are little white spaces visible between.

[This illustrates the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77TEc.png)

I'd like to make my buttons appear as rectangles, with right angled corners, is this possible? I assume this might be possible with CSS, but I can't find this question being asked before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do Via CSS :

```
"-fx-background-radius: 0"
```

You can add your CSS file in several ways by code , by Inline , External file

> **By Code :**

```
Button rectangleButton = new Button();
roundButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0");
```

> **By FXML Inline :**

[image]

> **By FXML External :**

mystyle.css file

```
.button{
-fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

then choose directory of file to apply the style to your container

[image]

Comment: Taking the amout of buttons in the linked image in the question into account it would probably be better to use a external stylesheet to apply the rule to multiple `Button`s at once.

Comment: Well, it really depends on it's programme that's mean he will apply CSS to all buttons not excluding any !!

Comment: It's not necessary to apply the stylesheet to the root. Furthermore you could also select the buttons taking the parent into account, e.g. `.container>.button {}`

Comment: Great solution, making appropriate container and apply CSS styles to that container.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Comment: You're welcome mark it as Accepted Answer if you see it's the right one. @bigfam